# "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied" when accessing file path in MAUI app

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I'm trying to add the zip file (contains .s3db file) in my .NET 7 MAUI app.
I am able to create a directory. But, when I try to delete the file or use `File.WriteAllBytes()`, it throws "Access to the path is denied".

I have tried both `System.Environment` and `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory` to access the directory.

```cs
ZipDBPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TempSD", "StaticData.zip")

ZipDBPathDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TempSD");

if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
{
    File.Delete(App.ZipDBPath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(App.ZipDBPath);
    File.WriteAllBytes(App.ZipDBPath, data);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(App.ZipDBPath, App.ZipDBPathDir);
    File.Delete(App.ZipDBPath);
}
```

NOTE: I also have the same code block in xamarin.forms project and it is Working fine.

Comment: Are you sure the folder exists?  You are using the full file path when calling CreateDirectory

Comment: You can skip the first line `File.Delete(App.ZipDBPath);`.
Second line creates a new zip file with 0kb.
Third line line throws the Error.

Comment: according to the docs, `CreateDirectory` should throw an exception if it is given a file path.  I'd try calling it with just the folder path to see if that makes any difference.